# How to test Chosser has been launched in unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am having an API which launched chooser, and need to test it.
Is there any way by which we can test ACTION_CHOOSER?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest delegate a launch chooser to seperate class and after that mock this **util class/launch function** for tests purposes.